# Create a .nonmedia File in Android doesnt work

Tags: android, file, sd-card

My App creates and use some images from the sd-card. 
These images are shown in the gallery of the device, but i dont want that.
So i tried to create a .nonmedia file in this directory, but my problem is that this file wont be created.

Heres the code:

```
public void createNonmediaFile(){
    String text = "NONEMEDIA";
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" +  AVATARS + "/.nonmedia";
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
        fos.write(text.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

There are no exceptions.

I gues it has something to do with the "." in the name. If i try the same whithout it, the file gets created.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The file should be called `.nomedia`. Note the spelling difference from what you have.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following example

```
    File file = new File(directoryPath, ".nomedia");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put below permission in your android-manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And then below code should work just fine:

```
private static final String AVATARS = "avatars";
public void createNonmediaFile(){
    String text = "NONEMEDIA";
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" +  AVATARS + "/.nonmedia";
    String f = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" +  AVATARS ;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        File folder = new File(f);
        boolean success=false;
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            success = folder.mkdir();
        }
        if (true==success) {
            File yourFile = new File(path);
            if(!yourFile.exists()) {
                yourFile.createNewFile();
            } 
        } else {
        // Do something else on failure 
        }
        fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
        fos.write(text.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```